# Mule Anypoint Studio - Test Connection Failed - Unknown Error while doing connectivity testing - Custom API

Tags: api, integration, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

I am new to Mule and learning. I downloaded Anypoint Studio and successfully developed and deployed 3 stand alone system APIs to cloud hub. They work via Postman.

Now I want to create a 4th API which is a Process API which will call these 3 system APIs in order. My understanding of API-Led Connectivity is like APIs calling APIs for re-usability.

So I went to the palette and downloaded my 3 published APIs from the Exchange. I dragged and dropped the first one. It asked me to configure. When I provide the values it's failing. That API works fine when I test it via Postman. What mistake am I doing here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Trying to further understand. Are you trying to create a flow in studio that would call either of the 3 API's created and deployed in cloudhub ? . Also, you are are able to call the 3 API's deployed in cloudhub using POSTMAN but unable to call it from studio. Am i stating your question correctly ?    Coudl you also explain as to why you imported the 3 API's in your studio since they are already running in cloudhub.

Comment: If I want to use it in my 4th API - I should be pulling them down to my AnyPoint studio in my local machine. It's not the cloud version that I am using. Thank you for trying to help me there. It looks like the answer is - I must have used upper case HTTP

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the answer is very easy. I should have used upper case letters as HTTP instead of http